# Error when computing summaries in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to use TensorFlow to produce summaries and visualize them using TensorBoard. However, I am getting an error (`InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float`) that I do not understand.

This is the full source of my program:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

_ = tf.histogram_summary("weights", W)
_ = tf.histogram_summary("biases", b)
_ = tf.histogram_summary("y", y)


y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

with tf.name_scope("xent") as scope:
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
    _ = tf.scalar_summary("cross entropy", cross_entropy)

with tf.name_scope("train") as scope:
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess =  tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

with tf.name_scope("test") as scope:
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    _ = tf.scalar_summary("accuracy", accuracy)

merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/tmp/mnist_nn", sess.graph_def)

for i in range(1000):
    if (i % 10) == 0:
        feed = {x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}
        result = sess.run([merged, accuracy], feed_dict=feed) 
        summary_str = result[0]
        acc = result[1]
        print("Accuracy at step %s: %s" % (i, acc))
    else:
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        feed = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=feed)

print(accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

However, when I attempt to run the above code, the following error is raised:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-584a7bc91816> in <module>()
     39     if (i % 10) == 0:
     40         feed = {x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}
---> 41         result = sess.run([merged, accuracy], feed_dict=feed)
     42         summary_str = result[0]
     43         acc = result[1]

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict)
    366 
    367     # Run request and get response.
--> 368     results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
    369 
    370     # User may have fetched the same tensor multiple times, but we

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict)
    442         # pylint: disable=protected-access
    443         raise errors._make_specific_exception(node_def, op, error_message,
--> 444                                               e.code)
    445         # pylint: enable=protected-access
    446       six.reraise(e_type, e_value, e_traceback)

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'Placeholder_1', defined at:
```

It seems from the error that a placeholder in my source has not been fed an appropriate value. As far as I can tell, I am feeding values for all of the placeholders (`x` and `y_`).

If you need I'll add the full log to this issue.

I also found that when I first fetch mnist, it does work (with the following output) but still no TensorBoard visualization is produced:

```
Successfully downloaded train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 9912422 bytes.
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 28881 bytes.
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 1648877 bytes.
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 4542 bytes.
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Tensor("MergeSummary/MergeSummary:0", shape=TensorShape([]), dtype=string)
merged
Accuracy at step 0: 0.098
Accuracy at step 10: 0.7404
Accuracy at step 20: 0.8041
Accuracy at step 30: 0.814 ...
```

Answer (score 13):

From your error message, it looks like you are using IPython. One pitfall when using IPython to build a TensorFlow model is that functions like [`tf.merge_all_summaries()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/train.html#merge_all_summaries) will remember every summary created in the current session, including cells that failed with an error. This is a result of TensorFlow using a **default graph** to collect all of the operations, summaries, etc. that are created in a process, unless you specify the graph explicitly. I suspect that your call to `tf.merge_all_summaries()` is returning more than the three histogram summaries that you created in your code, and the older ones will have a dependency on a *previously created* placeholder.

There are two main ways that you could fix that. The simplest is to explicitly merge the summaries, rather than using `tf.merge_all_summaries()`:

```
weights_summary = tf.histogram_summary("weights", W)
biases_summary = tf.histogram_summary("biases", b)
y_summary = tf.histogram_summary("y", y)

merged = tf.merge_summary([weights_summary, biases_summary, y_summary])
```

An alternative would be to set an **explicit default graph** before constructing your model. This is awkward if you want to split your model across multiple IPython cells, but should also work:

```
# Sets a new default graph, and stores it in `g`.
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:  

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    # ...

    # Summaries are added to `g`.
    _ = tf.histogram_summary("weights", W)
    _ = tf.histogram_summary("biases", b)
    _ = tf.histogram_summary("y", y)

    # ...

    # `merged` contains only summaries from `g`.
    merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()

    # ...
```

Comment: So is it 'best practise' to not to use interactive sessions - neither of the solutions seem ideal. One would have hoped there would be a way of 'clearing' the default graph

Comment: You can clear the default graph by calling `tf.reset_default_graph()`, but any previously created `tf.InteractiveSession` objects won't see any newly created nodes. I'd recommend steering clear of any functions that implicitly depend on "all" previously created objects (`tf.merge_all_summaries()`, `tf.initialize_all_variables()`) if you have complex IPython sessions that span multiple cells.

Answer (score 6):

**for keras users**

you might encounter this error when using the TensorBoard callback and fitting a *new* model from scratch. In this case, the solution is to call

```
from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
```

before creating the new model. verified with keras 2.1.5 and tensorflow 1.6.0

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more, this should be highly featured in the keras manual. Bit me too.