# InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [1000,625]

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I get the above unexpected error when trying to run this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Jun 24 10:38:04 2016

@author: andrea
"""

# pylint: disable=missing-docstring
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import time

from six.moves import xrange  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
import tensorflow as tf
from pylab import *
import argparse
import mlp

# Basic model parameters as external flags.
tf.app.flags.FLAGS = tf.python.platform.flags._FlagValues()
tf.app.flags._global_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 'Initial learning rate.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('max_steps', 20, 'Number of steps to run trainer.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 1000, 'Batch size. Must divide evenly into the dataset sizes.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_samples', 100000, 'Total number of samples. Needed by the reader')
flags.DEFINE_string('training_set_file', 'godzilla_dataset_size625', 'Training set file')
flags.DEFINE_string('test_set_file', 'godzilla_testset_size625', 'Test set file')
flags.DEFINE_string('test_size', 1000, 'Test set size')


def placeholder_inputs(batch_size):

    images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, mlp.NUM_INPUT))
    labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, mlp.NUM_OUTPUT))
    return images_placeholder, labels_placeholder


def fill_feed_dict(data_set_file, images_pl, labels_pl):

    for l in range(int(FLAGS.num_samples/FLAGS.batch_size)):
        data_set = genfromtxt("../dataset/" + data_set_file, skip_header=l*FLAGS.batch_size, max_rows=FLAGS.batch_size)
        data_set = reshape(data_set, [FLAGS.batch_size, mlp.NUM_INPUT + mlp.NUM_OUTPUT])
        images = data_set[:, :mlp.NUM_INPUT]
        labels_feed = reshape(data_set[:, mlp.NUM_INPUT:], [FLAGS.batch_size, mlp.NUM_OUTPUT])
        images_feed = reshape(images, [FLAGS.batch_size, mlp.NUM_INPUT])

        feed_dict = {
            images_pl: images_feed,
            labels_pl: labels_feed,
        }

        yield feed_dict

def reader(data_set_file, images_pl, labels_pl):

    data_set = loadtxt("../dataset/" + data_set_file)
    images = data_set[:, :mlp.NUM_INPUT]
    labels_feed = reshape(data_set[:, mlp.NUM_INPUT:], [data_set.shape[0], mlp.NUM_OUTPUT])
    images_feed = reshape(images, [data_set.shape[0], mlp.NUM_INPUT])

    feed_dict = {
        images_pl: images_feed,
        labels_pl: labels_feed,
    }

    return feed_dict, labels_pl


def run_training():

    tot_training_loss = []
    tot_test_loss = []
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
        images_placeholder, labels_placeholder = placeholder_inputs(FLAGS.batch_size)    
        test_images_pl, test_labels_pl = placeholder_inputs(FLAGS.test_size)
        logits = mlp.inference(images_placeholder)      
        test_pred = mlp.inference(test_images_pl, reuse=True)
        loss = mlp.loss(logits, labels_placeholder)
        test_loss = mlp.loss(test_pred, test_labels_pl)
        train_op = mlp.training(loss, FLAGS.learning_rate)

        #summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        sess = tf.Session()
        #summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("./", sess.graph)

        sess.run(init)
        test_feed, test_labels_placeholder = reader(FLAGS.test_set_file, test_images_pl, test_labels_pl)

        # Start the training loop.
        for step in xrange(FLAGS.max_steps):
            start_time = time.time()
            feed_gen = fill_feed_dict(FLAGS.training_set_file, images_placeholder, labels_placeholder)
            i=1
            for feed_dict in feed_gen:
                _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
                _, test_loss_val = sess.run([test_pred, test_loss], feed_dict=test_feed)
                tot_training_loss.append(loss_value)
                tot_test_loss.append(test_loss_val)
                #if i % 10 == 0:
                #print('%d minibatches analyzed...'%i)
                i+=1

            if step % 1 == 0:        
                duration = time.time() - start_time
                print('Epoch %d (%.3f sec):\n training loss = %f \n test loss = %f ' % (step, duration, loss_value, test_loss_val))

        predictions = sess.run(test_pred, feed_dict=test_feed)
        savetxt("predictions", predictions)
        savetxt("training_loss", tot_training_loss)
        savetxt("test_loss", tot_test_loss)
        plot(tot_training_loss)    
        plot(tot_test_loss)
        figure()
        scatter(test_feed[test_labels_placeholder], predictions)

  #plot([.4, .6], [.4, .6])

run_training()


#if __name__ == '__main__':
#  tf.app.run()
```

this is mlp:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import math

import tensorflow as tf

NUM_OUTPUT = 1
NUM_INPUT = 625
NUM_HIDDEN = 5

def inference(images, reuse=None):
    with tf.variable_scope('hidden1', reuse=reuse):
        weights = tf.get_variable(name='weights', shape=[NUM_INPUT, NUM_HIDDEN], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        weight_decay = tf.mul(tf.nn.l2_loss(weights), 0.00001, name='weight_loss')
        tf.add_to_collection('losses', weight_decay)
        biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, name='biases', shape=[NUM_HIDDEN]))
        hidden1_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(images, weights)+biases, name='hidden1')

    with tf.variable_scope('output', reuse=reuse):
        weights = tf.get_variable(name='weights', shape=[NUM_HIDDEN, NUM_OUTPUT], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        weight_decay = tf.mul(tf.nn.l2_loss(weights), 0.00001, name='weight_loss')
        tf.add_to_collection('losses', weight_decay)
        biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, name='biases', shape=[NUM_OUTPUT]))
        output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden1_output, weights)+biases, name='output')

    return output

def loss(outputs, labels):

  rmse = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(labels, outputs))), name="rmse")
  tf.add_to_collection('losses', rmse)
  return tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')


def training(loss, learning_rate):

  tf.scalar_summary(loss.op.name, loss)
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
  global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
  train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
  return train_op
```

here the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-f16dfed3b99b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/andrea/test/python/main_mlp_yield.py', wdir='/home/andrea/test/python')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/andrea/test/python/main_mlp_yield.py", line 127, in <module>
    run_training()

  File "/home/andrea/test/python/main_mlp_yield.py", line 105, in run_training
    _, test_loss_val = sess.run([test_pred, test_loss], feed_dict=test_feed)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [1000,625]
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[1000,625], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/start_ipython_kernel.py", line 205, in <module>
    __ipythonkernel__.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 442, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 162, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 883, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 391, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 199, in do_execute
    shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2723, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2831, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-f16dfed3b99b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/andrea/test/python/main_mlp_yield.py', wdir='/home/andrea/test/python')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/andrea/test/python/main_mlp_yield.py", line 127, in <module>
    run_training()
  File "/home/andrea/test/python/main_mlp_yield.py", line 79, in run_training
    images_placeholder, labels_placeholder = placeholder_inputs(FLAGS.batch_size)
  File "/home/andrea/test/python/main_mlp_yield.py", line 37, in placeholder_inputs
    images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, mlp.NUM_INPUT))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 895, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1238, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 704, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2260, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1230, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

I really don't understand why. It looks to me that I'm feeding all the placeholders before using them. I also removed the "merge_all_summaries" since this problem is similar to other ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413618/tensorflow-placeholder-error-when-using-tf-merge-all-summaries) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114376/error-when-computing-summaries-in-tensorflow)), but it didn't help

EDIT: training data: 100000 samples x 625 features
test data: 1000 samples x 625 features
num. output: 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is in this code:

```
def loss(outputs, labels):
  rmse = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(labels, outputs))), name="rmse")
  tf.add_to_collection('losses', rmse)
  return tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')
```

You're adding up all the losses from collection 'losses', including both your training and test losses. In particular, in this code:

```
loss = mlp.loss(logits, labels_placeholder)
test_loss = mlp.loss(test_pred, test_labels_pl)
```

The first call to mlp.loss will add training losses to the 'losses' collection. The second call to mlp.loss will incorporate those values in its result. So when you try to compute the test_loss, Tensorflow complains that you didn't feed all of the inputs (the training placeholders).

Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
def loss(outputs, labels):
  rmse = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(labels, outputs))), name="rmse")
  return rmse
```

I hope that helps!